# Directory Reader Applet Loads in Eclipse, but not in Browser

Tags: java, security, browser, applet, directory

I'm fairly new to programming and I just wrote an applet program that is supposed to list the files in a directory.  The applet works well in eclipse, yet the issue is when I attempt to run the applet in a browser the GUI loads, yet the applet will not respond as it does in eclipse.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class DirReader extends JApplet{

private JTextArea outputWindow;

private JTextField dirPath;
private String path;
private Font font;
private File folder;
private File[] listOfFiles;

public void init(){

    font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 16);

    dirPath = new JTextField("Enter Directory Path");
    dirPath.setFont(font);

    outputWindow = new JTextArea();
    outputWindow.setEditable(false);
    outputWindow.setFont(font);
    outputWindow.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    outputWindow.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);           

    add(dirPath, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(outputWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setSize(400,750);

    dirPath.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                path = dirPath.getText();
                folder = new File(path);
                listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                System.out.println("Directory path set");
                ListOfFiles();
            }               
        }
    );

    System.out.println("Progam Intilized:");
}

public void ListOfFiles(){

    outputWindow.setText(null);

    try{
        for(int counter = 0 ; counter < listOfFiles.length ; counter++ ){               

            if(listOfFiles[counter].isFile()){  
                outputWindow.append("[FILE] " + listOfFiles[counter].getName()+ "\n");
                System.out.println("[FILE] " + listOfFiles[counter].getName());
            }
            else if(listOfFiles[counter].isDirectory()){
                outputWindow.append("[DIR] " + listOfFiles[counter].getName() + "\n");
                System.out.println("[DIR] " + listOfFiles[counter].getName());
            }                           
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Directory could not be found.");

        outputWindow.setText("Error: Could not find directory.");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it does NOT work in browser

Because

when applet run in a browser as a security precaution there is no access to read files on the local file system.

**Solution**

Make your program as a **Desktop application** run in desktop NOT **Applet** run in browser

Comment: The only issue is that this program is supposed to be for a website so that it will read the files in the website's directory.  If you have any suggestions it would be most appreciated :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. An untrusted applet cannot get a directory listing
2. A trusted applet cannot get a directory listing on the server (only the client).
3. For an applet to gain a file listing on the server, it will need to be explicitly told what the files are.  Two common ways are:

   - Add the file list as parameters for the applet.
   - Have the applet access server side functionality to get a file listing.

BTW:

```
}catch(Exception e){
```

Should become..

```
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(); //...
```

Be sure to figure out how to access the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) to see the output.  Debugging applets without that information is like trying to debug wearing a blind-fold.